# Laravel Foreign key Referencing table in External database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I'm new to Laravel and databases in general. I'm writing a web application for student evaluations. I have an existing MySQL database that contains everything I need already; however, I am using Laravel's auth user table and trying to add a foreign key that references a Teacher table in the MySQL database. I keep getting the following error...

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

> In Connection.php line 664:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_teacher_id_foreign` 
>   foreign key (`teacher_id`) references `p4j`.`teacher` (`teacher_id`))
>
> In Connection.php line 458: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot
>   add foreign key constraint

My code is as follows...

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DP_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'p4j'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DP_PASSWORD', '**mypassword**'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

**database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('teacher_id')->unsigned();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('teacher_id')->on('p4j.teacher');
    });
}
```

**app/User.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'teacher_id'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple possible issues and solutions are that your db engine is not INNODB or loading order of migration files is incorrect. For the first solution you need to add `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` inside of `Schema::create` and if this doesn't fix the issue, i'll need you to post the names of your users and teacher migrations

**Possible fix:**

> Both PRIMARY KEY constraint and UNIQUE constraint uses to enforce Entity integrity (defines a row as a unique entity for a particular table), but primary keys do not allow null values. Specifies the column that uniquely identifies a row in the table. The identified columns must be defined as NOT NULL.

And since laravel [increment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns) function also

> Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column.

Simply removing `->default(null);` and rerunning migrations should potentially fix the problem.

Comment: Okay I added 'InnoDB' to both tables.

Here are the file names:
2018_02_08_000003_create_domain_table.php
2018_02_08_000004_create_teacher_table.php
2018_02_08_000005_create_student_table.php
2018_02_08_000006_create_criteria_table.php
2018_02_08_000007_create_evaluation_table.php
2018_02_08_000008_create_eval_criteria_choice_table.php
2018_02_08_000009_create_users_table2.php

Comment: Okay, the file names are in correct order, could you now post the contents of the create_teacher_table migration file to pastebin or some other code dump online service and post a link here? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error after removing ->default(NULL)

Comment: Thats a bit odd, could you add another column into users migration and run migrations again and check if the new column has been added inside the table, laravel mightve cached your migration files

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that the data type of the foreign key (p4j.teacher.teacher_id) corresponds to the same data type of the `teacher_id` column in your users table.

We need to see the structure of the p4j.teacher table.

Comment: They are both unsigned integers. You can see the p4j.teacher migration in my comment on Nikola's answer.

Comment: But do they have the same number of max digits? It wont work if one is INT and the other is BIGINT